# Gmail stop redirecting me to Google Inbox

Tags: gmail, inbox-by-gmail

I access my **Gmail** account from Firefox and when I log into gmail.com, my account seems to redirect to **Google Inbox** (*inbox.google.com*) rather than the **Gmail** (*mail.google.com*) interface I want to see and that I thought was the default.

I have been unable to find anything in the settings to stop this behavior.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short Version**

1. Go to your mail account.
2. Settings -> Other -> uncheck `Redirect Gmail to inbox.google.com`

---

**Detailed Version**

1. Click here to show the **Settings** and other options (scroll down
   if needed)
   [image]
2. Click on **Settings**

[image]

3. Click on **Other** and be sure the **Redirect Gmail to inbox.google.com** is ***un***checked

[image]